# I am always receiving the error "Content not allowed in prolog" in Android Studio even with built-in android studio apps

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I seem to always be getting the error: "content not allowed in prolog", even when using the built-in android studio apps. Not sure what is happening. Please help! Using Android Studio 4.0 and android gradle plugin version 4.0.0 and gradle version 6.1.1 according to my project structure if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Close android studio.
2. Delete all the contents of below directories.

   ```
   C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\build-cache
   C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\cache
   C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches
   ```
3. Start Android Studio.